# Supposed method of integration: “long dividing” by $d$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I came across [this](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2018/10/31/integration-by-long-division/) seemingly interesting, but poorly exemplified, method of integrating:

> Since integration is the inverse of differentiation, you can think of integration as “dividing” by $d$.
>
> J. P. Ballantine [1] shows that you can formally divide by $d$ and get the correct integral. For example, he arrives at $$\int x^2 \sin x\,dx=(2-x^2)\cos x + 2x\sin x + C$$ using long division!
>
> [image: poor example]
>
> [1] J. P. Ballantine. Integration by Long Division. The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 58, No. 2 (Feb., 1951), pp. 104-105

Surely the claim that this is rigorous is questionable. However, it would be fascinating to understand how to follow this method and maybe even understand why it works; the example has no explanation, and I can’t put the steps together via reverse engineering.

**Could someone shed some light on this technique?**

addendum: An additional example would really complete the perfect response $\ddot\smile$

Comment: "Formal" doesn't mean rigorous here, it means based on form; messing around with the symbols without worrying too much about whether they mean anything. Euler famously did this sort of thing a lot.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Gotcha! Thank you for specifying that; that distinction makes a lot more sense than what I thought. I’ve made a revision ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to "reverse engineer" the steps and I am going to go through them for you!

First, write the function you wish to integrate on the left

$$x^2 \sin x\ dx$$

Now find a function such that, when you differentiate it, the $x^2 \sin x$ comes up. Ah! When you differentiate $-x^2 \cos x$ you get $x^2 \sin x - 2x \cos x$, so it has the bit you want and the other bit seems "smaller" in the sense of "degree" or something. Just write that $-x^2 \cos x$ on the side, differentiate it and subtract the derivative, getting:

[image]

Now it's like we found an anti-derivative for the function we want to integrate, but in doing so we got the extra term $2x \cos x$ that we need to cancel... Think of something that, when differentiated, arrives at $-2x \cos x$... Ah! When you differentiate $2x \sin x$, you get the $2x \cos x$ and an extra $2 \sin x$. Write the $2x \sin x$ on the right, differentiate it, and subtract from whatever you had, getting:

[image]

and you keep going. The point being, you are always trying to come up with something (in some sense, smaller) that counters the leftovers you have from finding the anti-derivatives of the other terms!

Was I clear enough?

---

Let us integrate $x \log x$ just for the fun of it. Can you come up with something that, when differentiated, gives $x \log x + $ something? Of course you can, just notice that $(\frac12x^2\log x)' = x\log x + \frac12 x$

So we now have to deal with the extra $-\frac12 x$.

Can you come up with something that cancels that $-\frac12 x$? Of course you can, because $-\frac14 x^2$ does it! We now get

$$0$$

meaning we are done and

$$\int x \log x = \frac12 x^2 \log x - \frac14 x^2 + C$$

Comment: It’s like only doing half of the product rule! isn’t it?

Comment: “$x\log x +\text{something}$”: That’s the key point right there. If you don’t mind, I’m going to ruminate on that for a bit, then I’ll probably come back and mark this answer $\color{green}{\checkmark}$—but first I’ll let other people contribute their fair shares too $\ddot\smile$

Comment: sure thing @ChaseRyanTaylor . I tried to include a picture of the division process but I couldn't. Do you want me to further develop my answer?

Comment: @RGS I followed it just fine. And actually, I think “long division” is a misleading name. The subtraction pattern is a way to keep track of the terms you have left to reconcile, like you do with place values / partial fractions in long division, but whence the author got this “‘dividing’ by $d$” notion is beyond me. . . .

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor sorry nobody chipped in in the meantime